# How to Output Image URL's to Console Log Using Javascript Or Jquery In Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add all the image url that I click on any particular page to a variable , so that I can get the image URL in console .

All this code is supposed to run in console .

I am using this code now :

```
var x = document.images;
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + x[i].src + "\n";
}
```

This Works but It outputs all image Urls present on the page , I need only the Images I click On , given there is no href link attached to the images .

Also , If I want only images starting with a specific domain on that page , Like Only Imgur images URL etc ... Instead of all .

Comment: between the two answers you have what you need, but maybe slightly easier on the eyes: `$("img").on("click", function(){ clickedImages.push(this.src);});`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with jQuery :

```
jQuery(function($){
    var clickedImages = [];

    // Images whose URL starts with
    $('img[src^="http://i.imgur.com"]').click(function(e){
         var $img = $(this);
         clickedImages.push( $img.attr('src') );
    });

    // And when you want :
    console.log(clickedImages); // will display the javascript array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real basic working example. In my example, there are placeholder images from two different domain names. However, only the ones with `placehold.it` in the URL will be shown in console.

Yes, you can get more complicated with the `if` statement by using `regex`, but this is just a simple working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on("click","img",function(){
    this_src = $(this).attr("src");
    if(this_src.indexOf("placehold.it") > -1){
        console.log(this_src);
      }
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/350/150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/350/150">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want image URLs added when you click on them, your code should be in a click event handler--it doesn't really matter if you use javascript or jQuery for that. Furthermore, to only get imgur images, while it is possible in plain javascript, jQuery does have something that can work nicely for this situation, called the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). It works by only selecting elements which have the specified string in their attributes, like so:

```
var txt = "";

$("img[src*='egdomain']").click(function() {
    txt = txt + $(this).attr("src") + "\n";
})
```

With this code, only images with a `src` of 'egdomain' will even be selected to have their URLs added to the text. And as more of a suggestion, you can make your `txt` variable an array, push the URLs in there, then print them out with a for loop whenever you're ready to print them out really, like so:

```
var txt = [];

$("img[src*='egdomain']").click(function() {
    txt.push($(this).attr("src"))
})

function displayURLs() {
    var numURLs = txt.length;
    var i;

    for (i=0; i < numURLs; i++) {
        console.log(txt[i]);
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps, good luck in your endeavors.

Comment: Getting Error in console - VM2067:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I just edited out my mistakes. As this is jQuery, you need to have jQuery included in your page for this to work; in addition, it's always a good idea to wrap your javascript in $(document).ready(function(){//your code here}) (again, a jQuery function)